# Xcode instrument don't run because this error "the target device service is too old"

Tags: xcode, instruments

when I try to run instrument core graphics test I find error like this "the target device service is too old"

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Xcode Instruments Core Animations requires you to use the device. So instead of running it on the simulator, run it on your device.

`The target device service is too old` is shown when the simulator is selected.

## Solution:

- In Xcode Instruments > Core Animation, run it on the **device** (your iPhone / iPad)

Comment: Can you explain more please or add some photos.

Comment: In Xcode instruments, Next to the record red button, there would be a pause button, next to that you can choose simulator / device. It is similar to that in Xcode.

Comment: Run it on your device instead of simulator

Comment: Ok, if I do that did the improvement that I make it on my device applying for the another devices?